# Handling "Save resources" dialog user choice

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am having an RCP application managing a specific data model saved in a file. There is a merge-compare functionality based on org.eclipse.compare.* API.

When closing the merge-compare view, in case of an unsaved data, a "Save resources" dialog appears by default.

The problem is that I don't find mechanism to "inform" the merge-compare view what the user has chosen and as a result the data is not saved on close of the view.

In general, my question is how to invoke the save functionality depending on what has been selected from the "Save resources" dialog?
Excluding this case, the save functionality in the merge-compare view is handled with a listener for a save command (e.g Save All, Save), but the save initiated from the dialog is not handled this way.

Answer (score 0):

i faced problem similar somehow of urs 
i want to ask user if he want to save some files in text editor but not all files

so i used

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().saveAll(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow(), PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow(), filter, true);
```